# JavaFX GIF is not displayed in the user interface

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, gif

I have a user interface with images attached to it and for some reason the added GIF is not displayed in the UI and no error is given. I have a test label created as well and this is displayed. There is just blank area instead of the gif. Here's the code:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

import java.io.File;

public class CheckoutGrid extends GridPane {

    private final RefactoredUserInterface UI;
    private ImageView checkoutLoadingGif;

    public CheckoutGrid(RefactoredUserInterface userInterface) {
        this.UI = userInterface;
        this.checkoutLoadingGif = setupLoadingGif("checkoutLoading.gif");
        add(checkoutLoadingGif, 0, 0);
        add(new Label("Test"), 1, 1);
    }

    private ImageView setupLoadingGif(String gifName) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setImage(new Image(new File(gifName).toURI().toString()));
        imageView.setFitWidth(120);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        imageView.setSmooth(true);
        imageView.setCache(true);
        imageView.setVisible(true);
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
I changed the following part:

```
imageView.setImage(new Image(new File(gifName).toURI().toString()));
```

to:

```
imageView.setImage(new Image(gifName));
```

and removed the setVisible() parameter and it started to work.. I have no reason why, though.

Comment: Did you try "imageView.setImage(new Image(new File(gifName).toURI().toURL().toExternalForm()));"?

Comment: The [`Image`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) constructor will interpret a string path that is not a URL relative to the class path. The [`File.toURI()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toURI--) method will resolve the path against the user's working directory (via the `getAbsolutePath()` method). So presumably the file you specify is deployed at the root of the classpath, which is (apparently) not the same as the user's working directory when you are running the application in this case.